# Global POST always empty

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

the `$_POST` varyable is always empty in my Codeigniter controller:

controllers/Register.php

```
class Register extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('register.html');

    }

    public function user()
    {
        var_dump($_POST);

    }

}
```

views/register.html (view)

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="register/user">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That is my `.htaccess`, i'm using it to remove `index.php` from my URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

`var_dump($_POST)` always output `array(0) { }`, but `$_GET` works fine. I'm on Linux (Arch), using Apache, Codeigniter 3, and PHP 7.

Sorry for my english. Thanks for all.

Edit:

`$this->input->post()` is empty too.

Comment: I'm betting that the CI framework is intercepting the $_POST and converting it to `$this->input->post()`.  Try `var_dump($this->input->post());`.  In CI 3 you have the option of allowing `$_GET` in the config file.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: I tried that before, same problem.

Comment: @vaati  `name` attributes for all the form elements are missing that is problem

Comment: OMG i can't believe. Sorry guys.

Comment: It is all ways good i think to use baseurl in `action="<?php echo base_url('register/user');?>"` make sure you have set base_url as it is required to do so in CI3 versions autoload the url helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main cause is `name` attributes from all the `form-elements` are missing

Like for example:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
```

It seems you confused between `id` and `name`.

`name` is the attribute picked-up by `$_POST`.

Comment: Also check the action="register/user" attribute on the form element. If anything attempts to redirect to add an ending slash to register/user/, it will drop the POST variables.

Comment: I changed my answer. I was answering another question and typed part of it here.